# Android Getting Survey Results In PieChart from JSON Need Roadmap

Tags: android, json

I created a piechart view with help of Android Developer site. I also store my survey results on my MySQL database. My JSON output is like this:

```
{"results":[{"CandidateNo":"110","VoteCount":"3"},{"CandidateNo":"1124","VoteCount":"1"}]}
```

In Android, I used this to getting results.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < result.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = sonuc.getJSONObject(i);

                        String CandidateNo = c.getString(TAG_NO);
                        String Result = c.getString(TAG_RESULT);

                        pie.addItem(TAG_NO,TAG_RESULT, color);


                    }
```

addItem method is like this:

```
 public int addItem(String label, float value, int color)
```

So the result value is float. But my TAG_RESULT is String. So it doesn't accept. What should i do about this, is my approach wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Float.valueOf(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#Float%28java.lang.String%29) to convert string to float.

Comment: Thanks for that, now it accepts the value, but i think my way to add item is wrong, since it crashes when it tries to add pie's.

Comment: @user3134811 I am new to pie, try asking new question with crash log & code.

Comment: I looked the crash log, the reason was i used the addItem on doInBackground, i put it to onPostExecute and now its fine.